# Parsing: Сollecting data from a book site

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

#### A task:

Сollect data from the site in the following format:
`book; user; book_rating; comment_rating; publication_date; comment`
For one book at once several pages of reviews (or more than one).

#### Problem:

One request to the site can be sent once every 0.25 seconds, so async requests don't work.

#### Question:

Can data collection be accelerated?

#### Сode structure:

Link to the page with the book from Top_link.txt
→ Get links to pages with reviews of this book (function score_link)
→ Get each review in a loop (function score_user)
→ Collect data from the review (function score_user)

#### Code:

```py
import os
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selectolax.lexbor import LexborHTMLParser
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm


# The function concatenates the current directory and the file name
def path_to_file(name):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), name)


# Read links to sites from top_link.txt
with open(path_to_file('top_link.txt'), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read()
book_id = [int(element.strip("'{}")) for element in text.split(", ")]
sites = [f"https://fantlab.ru/work{i}" for i in sorted(book_id)]

# Activate UserAgent
useragent = UserAgent()


# Get the html page and request response status.
def get_html(url):
    headers = {"Accept": "*/*", "User-Agent": useragent.random}
    # Establish a permanent connection
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = headers
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=100,
                                            pool_maxsize=100)
    session.mount('http://', ​​adapter)
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    html = resp.text
    return html, resp.status_code


# Get links to review pages
def score_link(html, url):
    tree = LexborHTMLParser(html)
    tree_users_list = tree.css_first(r'span.page-links')

    link_list = []
    # Users without this element have no reviews
    if tree_users_list is not None:
        tree_users = tree_users_list.css(r'a')
        for user in tree_users:
            # Link to comment page
            link = url + user.attributes['href']
            link_list.append(link)
        return link_list
    else:
        link_list.append(url)
        return link_list


# Get user feedback
def score_user(links):
    score_list = []

    # Follow links to review pages
    for url in links:
        html, status_code = get_html(url)
        tree = LexborHTMLParser(html)
        # Check server response
        if status_code == 200:
            score = tree.css("div.responses-list > div.response-item")
            if score is not None:
                # Go through reviews
                for user in score:
                    book_link = url.split('?')[0]
                    user_id = user.css_first(
                        r'p.response-autor-info>b>a').attributes['href']
                    book_rating = user.css_first(
                        r'div.clearfix>div.response-autor-mark>b>span').text()
                    comment_rating = user.css_first(
                        r'div.response-votetab>span:nth-of-type(2)').text()
                    data_score = user.css_first(
                        r'p.response-autor-info>span').attributes['content']
                    body_score = user.css_first(
                        r'div.response-body-home').text().replace('\n', ' ')
                    score_list.append(
                        f'{book_link};{user_id};{book_rating};{comment_rating};{data_score};{body_score}\n'
                    )
        elif status_code == 429:
            sleep(1)
            print('ERROE_429:', url)

        sleep(0.25)
    return score_list


with open(path_to_file("user.csv"), "a+", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(
        "book; user; book_rating; rating_rating; publication_date; comment \n"
    )
    for url in tqdm(sites):
        html, status_code = get_html(url)
        line = ''.join(score_user(score_link(html, url)))
        if line is not None:
            file.write(line)
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You ask if data collection can be accelerated. From the information you provide, it's hard to answer, because we cannot actually run the code, because some example data for `top_link.txt` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment under your post for why your question can hardly be answered accurately right now.

What I like about your code:

- Your main loop is nice and short, well done!
- You have a couple of functions that do one thing -- good!
- You use libraries appropriately!

Here's some general advice.

- You import `os` to resolve the absolute path of `top_link.txt`, which is in the same path as your script. Assuming the working directory is the one where your script resides, this is unnecessary. You can remove `path_to_file` and `import os`. This will speed up the startup of your script.
- You have function definitions and code in between each other. Create a `main` function with a `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard. I often place that at the top of all the function definitions, below imports and constants. That way I see the entry-point to your script easily.
- Since you ask for performance: You have a `sleep(0.5)` at the very bottom of the script, outside of the `for`-loop above it. I cannot think of a reason where that's necessary except if you start your script by double-clicking and want to wait half a second between main routine is finished and the window closing.
- You `user.csv` in read+append mode. Then you write a header. A header in CSV only makes sense in the first line of the file. That would mean you write a new file, otherwise you duplicate the header. I would recommend checking if the file exists with `pathlib.Path` (`os.path` works, but is not pythonic). Also, you never actually read from the file, so `a` mode is fine.
- If you use `pathlib.Path`, you can simplify reading `top_link.txt` to one simple function call that comes with `Path`.
- The beginning of `main` is there to create `sites`. After this is generated, you don't need `text` and `book_id` anymore. That is perfect to create a function.
- `if line is not None`: this can never be the case, since `"".join([])` is a `str` of length 0. So you probably want to check that you have a non-empty string. Then you can just write `if line:`.
- The same argument goes for `tree.css_first`. From the signature of that function it does not look like it could return `None`, but I'm not familiar with the library to be sure here.
- You have three different `sleep` times in your code, namely 0.25, 0.5, and 1. You only explained where one of these come from. This is an anti-pattern called "magic numbers". Replace them by constants with a good name.
- Your code had two ZWSPs (zero-width spaces) in it, which upset part of my IDE. I have removed them.
- Now to the meat of the script: `score_user` has 5 levels of indentation. That is *very* hard to read, and often a sign of convoluted code. Especially if you have nested ifs, you can reverse the logic of the conditions and `continue` the loop or `return` from the function early. That makes it clear what's happening in these cases without having to read the body of the big loop. I refactored that in a slightly unconventional way. I first checked if the status code is **not** 200 or 429 and handled that. Then I handled the case of 429. Then the rest of the function handles 200.
- Calculating the individual values of `score_list` looks fairly complex, and therefore deserves its own function.

If you apply these recommendations, the code looks like this.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

import requests
from requests import adapters
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selectolax.lexbor import LexborHTMLParser
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

RATE_LIMIT_DELAY = 1
MINIMUM_DELAY_BETWEEN_REQUESTS = 0.25

USER_CSV_PATH = Path("user.csv")
TOP_LINK_PATH = Path("top_link.txt")
CSV_HEADER = "book; user; book_rating; rating_rating; publication_date; comment \n"

# Activate UserAgent
useragent = UserAgent()


def main():
    sites = generate_sites_from_file(TOP_LINK_PATH)

    if not USER_CSV_PATH.exists():
        create_file_with_header(USER_CSV_PATH)

    with open("user.csv", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for url in tqdm(sites):
            html, status_code = get_html(url)
            line = "".join(score_user(score_link(html, url)))
            if line:
                file.write(line)


# Get the html page and request response status.
def get_html(url):
    headers = {"Accept": "*/*", "User-Agent": useragent.random}
    # Establish a permanent connection
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = headers
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=100, pool_maxsize=100)
    session.mount("http://", adapter)
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    html = resp.text
    return html, resp.status_code


# Get links to review pages
def score_link(html, url):
    tree = LexborHTMLParser(html)
    tree_users_list = tree.css_first(r"span.page-links")

    link_list = []
    # Users without this element have no reviews
    if tree_users_list is not None:
        tree_users = tree_users_list.css(r"a")
        for user in tree_users:
            # Link to comment page
            link = url + user.attributes["href"]
            link_list.append(link)
        return link_list
    else:
        link_list.append(url)
        return link_list


# Get user feedback
def score_user(links):
    score_list = []

    # Follow links to review pages
    for url in links:
        html, status_code = get_html(url)
        tree = LexborHTMLParser(html)
        # Check server response
        if status_code != 200:
            print(f'ERROR_{status_code}:{url}')
            sleep(RATE_LIMIT_DELAY)
            continue 

        # now status_code must be 200
        score = tree.css("div.responses-list > div.response-item")
        if score is not None:
            # Go through reviews
            for user in score:
                score_list.append(generate_score_list_entry(url, user))
        sleep(MINIMUM_DELAY_BETWEEN_REQUESTS)
    return score_list


def generate_score_list_entry(url, user):
    book_link = url.split("?")[0]
    user_id = user.css_first(r"p.response-autor-info>b>a").attributes["href"]
    book_rating = user.css_first(r"div.clearfix>div.response-autor-mark>b>span").text()
    comment_rating = user.css_first(r"div.response-votetab>span:nth-of-type(2)").text()
    data_score = user.css_first(r"p.response-autor-info>span").attributes["content"]
    body_score = user.css_first(r"div.response-body-home").text().replace("\n", " ")
    value = f"{book_link};{user_id};{book_rating};{comment_rating};{data_score};{body_score}\n"
    return value


def create_file_with_header(path: Path) -> None:
    with open(path, "w") as fd:
        fd.write(CSV_HEADER)


def generate_sites_from_file(path: Path) -> List[str]:
    text = path.read_text()
    book_id = [int(element.strip("'{}")) for element in text.split(", ")]
    return [f"https://fantlab.ru/work{i}" for i in sorted(book_id)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the precise and quick answer, I picked up a lot of useful information.

Comment: `ERROE_429` should be `ERROR_429` I assume.

Comment: That's how it was written in the original post. I kept it as is.